# Remove Extra Background behind the iPhone frame in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, ios

I have a 2 layers in Sketch the iPhone frame and the image in the background.

[image]

This is what it produces

[image]

Is there a way to hide or erase of that extra area using Sketch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try [masking the image with a shape](https://sketchapp.com/docs/shapes/masking/#mask-with-shape).

Make a rectangle with rounded corners in the middle of that phone border and use it to mask the image.

---

<sup><sub>I did this using an old version of Sketch, so there may be some differences.</sub></sup>

1. [I made a rectangle with the border hitting somewhere inside the phone border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uycIq.png) <sub><sup>Since the phone border is more than a few pixels thick, you don't have to make this very accurate. Just make sure it stays inside it.</sup></sub>

   - I'm not sure about the latest version of Sketch, but in mine, the fill of the shape layer needs to be unchecked or else the empty space within the masking rectangle shape will have the fill color. Although you can change this after you've masked it.
2. [Then I selected the shape layer + the image layer and used `Layer › Mask › Mask with Selected Shape`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU0FY.png)
3. [And finally, I arranged it behind the phone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwG4Y.png)

   - I did also add some shadow to the image layer afterward since both the masking shape layer and the image can be edited separately after the masking.